# in-expression compile-time check for constant expressions for older G++

Tags: c++, templates, compile-time, static-assert

I have the following macros for certain compile-time checks:

```
/* in-expression compile-time check evaluating to 0 */
#ifdef __cplusplus
template<bool> struct Chk_sa;
template<> struct Chk_sa<true>{};
#define Chk(test) (sizeof((Chk_sa<!!(0+(test))>())) * 0)
#else
#define Chk(test) (sizeof(struct { int (Chk):((0+(test)) ? 1 : -1); }) * 0)
#endif

/* ensure value x is a constant expression */
#ifdef __cplusplus
template<bool,bool> struct CEx_sa;
template<> struct CEx_sa<true,false>{};
template<> struct CEx_sa<false,true>{};
#define CEx(x) (sizeof((CEx_sa<!!(0+(x)), !(0+(x))>())) * 0 + (x))
#else
#define CEx(x) (sizeof(struct { int (CEx):(((0+(x)) && 1) + 1); }) * 0 + (x))
#endif

/* usage like this: */
struct ChkTest {
        int expr1[Chk(3*3) + 1];  // supposed to be [1]
        int expr2 : CEx(3*3);     // supposed to be : 9
};
```

However, the C++ part of this fails with a parse error already for uses of the `Chk` macro, at the `)` before the  `* 0` part. (I included the `CEx` part for completeness, as I’ll need both fixed.)

How can I change these to work with older G++ (GCC) versions? Specifically, these work on Debian etch (G++ 4.1.1) and fail on Debian sargs (G++ 3.3.5) and older.

(Note: I’m a C programmer but don’t really know C++.)

---

Update: the precise error message was requested. I saved the snippet above into a file `x`:

```
$ gcc -x c -c x
$ gcc -x c++ -c x
x:22: error: parse error before `)' token
x:23: error: parse error before `)' token
```

Comment: When you write *this fails with a parse error*, it's expected that you add the complete error message.

Comment: @273K it’s really not more than that but I added it in an edit to the post

Comment: For those of us who don't routinely have older versions of gcc installed, how about describing the "parse error".   It may also help if, using compilers that don't reject the code, if you give the result of the macro for various arguments.   Superficially, it's not clear to me that the macros are checking *anything* and, if they compile,  it appears that `Chk()` will give an expression that yields zero, and `CEx()` will give an expression that yields the same value as its argument (in both cases, possibly of different type).

Comment: Which GCC versions are we talking about?

Comment: @Peter I have done both. The expected values are shown in `//` comments at the bottom (yes, 0 and the expression), and the parse error is (when you add lots of whitespace) on the `)` before the ` * 0` as I wrote.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI I also wrote which GCC versions in the post…

Comment: gcc 3.x is hopeless I think. Why do you develop new code for it?

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI I’m writing a portability toolkit, and I had hopes of being able to include C++ equivalents where possible, though I don’t yet use those (I do use the C parts); while those GCC versions may be old, when it runs there it’ll also run on other UNIX compilers or even MSVC or something